# What is the difference and relationship between Scala Actors, Futures, Promises and Akka?

Tags: scala

what is the difference between Scala Futures and Promises, Actors and Akka.

They all appear to deal with concurrency, are they all just different ways of doing it or are they dependent upon each other?

Thanks

Comment: This might be relevant: http://www.slideshare.net/legendofklang/concurrency-scaladays

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn - thanks, was that a talk on youtube? if so do you have a link, thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJfS7K-Vkgk

Answer (score 3):

Taken from a larger context, they are different.

1. Akka is a library and contains several different implementations of Actors
2. Actor is a design pattern or some would argue design concept.
3. Promises and Futures are design patterns.

Since Futures and Promises are design patterns, your can have a Future which is backed by Akka library or if not using Akka, an Actor implementation.

Case in point, there is a `scala.actor.Future` implementation (deprecated, see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.actors.Future)) in the standard library. While if you look at `scala.concurrent.Future` (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future)) you can see that it's a trait. The fact that you're dealing with a trait and not a direct class with a fully concrete implementation should indicate that they're very open to letting other people implement other versions, backed by whatever.